# videojs fallback to download link

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, video.js

Along with Flash Fallback i also want that it should have a download link fallback. I think it can be achieved by Video tag . But i want to achieve it using javascript code as below . Could you please help !!

```
var videlem = document.createElement("video");
videlem.id="id";

     videlem.setAttribute('class',"video-js vjs-default-skin");
videlem.setAttribute('preload', "auto");
var sourceMP4 = document.createElement("source");
sourceMP4.setAttribute('src', url);
videlem.appendChild(sourceMP4);
var div = document.getElementById(div1);
div.appendChild(videlem);

  player=videojs({"controls": true , "techOrder": ["html5", "flash"]}, function(){
this.on("ended", function(){ 
console.log("VideoEnded") ;

});
});
```

I want that it should have fallback to Download Link . Please suggest me where should I put my code .

Thanks in advace .

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to how you're listening to the ended event you can listen to an error event. An error code of `4` means no source can be played.

```
player.on('error', function() {
  if (this.error().code === 4) {
    // Cannot play any source, show alternative
  }
})
```